# What is the correct way to dynamically set image src to remote url in React (18)

Tags: reactjs, react-image

I'm learning React (v18) and I've tried implementing some similar solutions that I've found here,  but so far no success.
I have been trying display "cards" with names and pictures from a list of authors; the url for the each picture is remote (for example from wikipedia):

```
export const Authors = () => {
    const authors = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Tayeb Salih',
            wikipedia: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tayeb_Salih',
            picture_url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Tayeb_saleh.jpg'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Adolfo Bioy Casares',
            wikipedia: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolfo_Bioy_Casares',
            picture_url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Bioy.png'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Lucy Foley',
            wikipedia: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_Foley',
            picture_url: 'https://www.intrinseca.com.br/upload/autor/Lucy%20Foley%20G.jpg'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Matt Ruff',
            wikipedia: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Ruff',
            picture_url: 'https://images.gr-assets.com/authors/1597587995p5/40577.jpg'
        }];  
    const cards:any[] = [];
    authors.forEach((author, index) => {
        const borderColor = index > 1 ? null : index > 0 ? '#57b60a' : '#b60a57';
        const item = (
            <Card borderColor={borderColor} title={author.name} subtitle={author.id.toString()} key={index}>
                <img src={require(`${author.picture_url}`)} alt={author.name} />
            </Card>
        );
        cards.push(item);
    });

    return (
        <section id="section-authors">
            <h1>Authors</h1>
            <div className="group-cards">
                {cards}
            </div>
            <img
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Bioy.png"
                alt=""
                height="200"
            />
        </section>
    );
};
```

In this way I get the following error: *Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Tayeb_saleh.jpg'*.

When I change the code to `<img src={require(author.picture_url)} alt={author.name} />`, the same error occurs.

If I trying use only `<img src={author.picture_url} alt={author.name} />`, error: *Uncaught Error: img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use ```` dangerouslySetInnerHTM*... then, with a little bit of insanity: ```<img src={ ````${author.picture_url}`} alt={author.name} />```... same error...

What's wrong anyway?

## **EDITED** including `<Card/>`

```
export const Card = (props: {
  title?: string | null | undefined;
  subtitle?: string | null | undefined;
  borderColor?: string | null | undefined;
  children?: any;
}) => {
    const cardStyle = {
        borderColor: props.borderColor || '#ded3d3',
    };

    return (
        <div className="card-minhoteca" style={cardStyle}>
            <CardHeader title={props.title} subtitle={props.subtitle} />
            <CardBody>
                {
                    React.Children.map(props.children, (child, i) => {
                        return React.cloneElement(child, { ...props, key: i });
                    })
                }
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter>
                <p>Card Footer</p>
            </CardFooter>
        </div>
    );
};

export const CardHeader = (props: { title?: string; subtitle?: string; }) => {
    return (
        <div className="card-header">
            <h3 className="title">{props.title}</h3>
            <h4 className="card-subtitle">{props.subtitle}</h4>
        </div>
    );
};

export const CardBody = (props: {
    children?: any
}) => {

    return (
        <div className="card-body">
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};


export const CardFooter = (props: {
    children?: any;
    callBack?: any;
}) => {
    return (
        <div className="card-footer">
            {props.children}
            <button onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                props.callBack();
            }}>Click!</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: This form is correct: `<img src={author.picture_url} alt={author.name} />`. Not sure why you're getting the void element error.

Comment: Please show the implementation of the `Card` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can use `{props.children}` in `Card` to render the children in the place needed. This should solve the error if you also changed the way of using `img` as the original answer.

In this use case, the `children` are not modified in their placement, which would not justify the use of `React.cloneElement()` over `props.children`. Hope this will help.

Example:

```
// Replaces Card component

export const Card = (props: {
  title?: string | null | undefined;
  subtitle?: string | null | undefined;
  borderColor?: string | null | undefined;
  children?: any;
}) => {
  const cardStyle = {
    borderColor: props.borderColor || '#ded3d3',
  };

  return (
    <div className="card-minhoteca" style={cardStyle}>
      <CardHeader title={props.title} subtitle={props.subtitle} />
      <CardBody>{props.children}</CardBody>
      <CardFooter>
        <p>Card Footer</p>
      </CardFooter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Original**

Instead of using `forEach` you can use `map()` to map out `authors`.

This way there is no need to create another `cards` array so component is cleaner.

Regarding the `img`, to pass the url it should be `<img src={author.pictureUrl} />`, I also changed the property name from `picture_url` to `pictureUrl` in `authors`.

If the issue remains, the error is in `Card` component. Maybe `{props.children}` was not placed properly, but will need to see the `Card` component to find out.

Example:

```
export const Authors = () => {
  const authors = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Tayeb Salih",
      wikipedia: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tayeb_Salih",
      pictureUrl:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Tayeb_saleh.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Adolfo Bioy Casares",
      wikipedia: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolfo_Bioy_Casares",
      pictureUrl:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Bioy.png",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Lucy Foley",
      wikipedia: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_Foley",
      pictureUrl:
        "https://www.intrinseca.com.br/upload/autor/Lucy%20Foley%20G.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Matt Ruff",
      wikipedia: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Ruff",
      pictureUrl: "https://images.gr-assets.com/authors/1597587995p5/40577.jpg",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <section id="section-authors">
      <h1>Authors</h1>
      <div className="group-cards">
        {authors.map((author, index) => {
          const borderColor =
            index > 1 ? null : index > 0 ? "#57b60a" : "#b60a57";
          return (
            <Card
              borderColor={borderColor}
              title={author.name}
              subtitle={author.id.toString()}
              key={index}
            >
              <img src={author.pictureUrl} alt={author.name} />
            </Card>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <img
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Bioy.png"
        alt=""
        height="200"
      />
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this observation, but the error about void element persist (Uncaught Error: img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTM) :(

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo Any chance the content of `<Card />` can be posted?

Comment: Of course! I don't believe that has anything specially in that but I have been edited the question including it.

Comment: This works too! Thanks. I accept your answer because is very well explained.

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo Glad that you solved it! It seems that the cause might be another issue somewhere else as you mentioned, but hopefully this still could help as a reference. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! Your answer helped me to make my code cleaner and more objective.

Answer (score 0):

Well... after debugging e read a lot the error message, I have understand that what I need was envolved the  in another tag; so, I used a  to envolve it and all starts to work fine. Now I understand that is necessary make a refactor in my components and its responsabilities too.